# flutter web blank index.html page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

My index.html opens a blank page after I release my flutter project for web, and there are some errors in Google Chrome Console:

However, my app works fine in debug mode.

[image]

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at /Users/behnam/Development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (6 months ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/behnam/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.61

• No issues found!
```

Comment: where are you hosting the site?

Comment: inside my directadmin panel where my Wordpress website hosted

Comment: also it shows same error when open file locally

Comment: if it is related to *Wordpress* you might include that tag

Comment: However, they have separate backends and have nothing in common.